# Should std::fread succeed if the file is large enough?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file

I have found the following strange behaviour on Visual Studio 2015 when reading a file for a large array of bytes. The file that I load is about 80 MB and is large enough.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::FILE* file;
  errno_t error = _wfopen_s(&file, L"/User/account/Desktop/file.data", L"r");

  const std::size_t n = 16384;
  std::vector<unsigned char> v(n);
  const std::size_t nb_bytes_read = std::fread(v.data(), sizeof(unsigned char), n, file);

  // At this point error = 0 and nb_bytes_read = 3473 
}
```

So I ask `std::fread` for 16384 bytes and it just gives me 3473 even though the file is large enough. Should it be considered as a bug? The standard does not seem to say so but this behavior is very weird to me.

Comment: @AMA: The variable `error` is set to 0 which means that the file has been loaded.

Comment: Try to open the file in binary mode `"rb"` which is propably what you want anyway.

Comment: @zett42: You are correct. I hate so much this "text mode" that I forgot it was existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open the file in binary mode `"rb"` which is propably what you want anyway. Otherwise, on the Windows platform, [the byte `\0x1A` terminates input](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes). Also, line breaks like `\r\n` will be converted to `\n` which may also result in less bytes read than specified.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your help. My code was running fine on Linux and failed when I moved to Windows. Do you thing that I should get ready for "short reads" in binary mode as explained by "John Zwinck".

Comment: @InsideLoop I don't think so. Nothing in the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fread) suggests the possibility of "short reads" (unless the function returns with an error). He already edited his answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: By the way, I have just realized that on Windows, it is so much faster to read 1 element of n bytes that n elements of 1 byte! There is no such difference on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/), `fread()` will only return fewer than the requested number of bytes if EOF was reached or an error occurred.  You can check for those with `feof()` and `ferror()`.

Comment: I understand. I am in the process of writing a File class that has its own internal buffer which size can be configured when opening the file. I am reading a binary file that can be considered as a binary JSON with a lot of small strings and small numbers such as double. The file is about 80 MB large and I realized that writing my own buffer of 16 kB speeds up the process a lot. When the process it empty, do you have any recommendation on which (size, count) to use to fill it?